# IE8 Form Not Submitting (Intermittent)

Tags: html, forms, asp-classic, internet-explorer-8, submit

I have a complex classic ASP system that has worked well for years but has recently started having a strange and intermittent problem.

On some forms, folks will report that they click "Submit" but that the form just resets itself (or, perhaps, the browser just reloads the form - my users are probably not able to tell the difference).

Most recently, this has happened to a user with IE8 (we do use ).  It seems to happen only with larger forms (ie. more data submitted).  We do use an empty action tag on the form to self-submit (ie. ) and we use POST.

We never heard about a problem like this until fairly recently.  At first, it seemed that it could be related to "Trusted Zone" settings on one user's machine, but we've gotten a few reports from other places now and it's less clear that it is a zone issue.  On my own machine, also running IE8, I never have a problem.

Any thoughts?

Comment: @don Can you provide a URL where this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler to see what's happening to the request?

Comment: Providing a URL would be tough - secure website and long/complicated form.  I have not used Fiddler before but will also give that a look.  Thanks.

Comment: What do your server logs say? As in, does the server think a POST occurred, or is it sitting there obliviously and the problem is actually with the client and/or the network?

Comment: The server logs do not say anything... nothing hits the server at all.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to force IE8 into compatibility mode, so that behaves in a similar manner to IE7.

To do this, you must place a special meta tag inside the <head> section of your page.  An ideal place to do this would be in a master page/template.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: We actually already use this tag, but thank you for the thought.