# Posting from IE8 to PHP gives blank $_POST

Tags: php, internet-explorer-8

I have a simple HTML form, sending a post request to a php script. In IE8, the form only works intermittently - most of the time the PHP script sees an empty $_POST variable.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Post test</title>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center;">
<?php

echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST, TRUE)."</pre>";

?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="moo" >
<input type="submit" value="Search" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Sometimes the print_r gives the response you'd expect (i.e. it's populated with the data from the form), most of the time it's empty.

Not being able to use POST is a bit of a problem for web applications - anyone got any ideas what's going on, and how to fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I've been sitting here clicking the button for 30 seconds and have never once seen a dropped POST. Are you sure there isn't a problem with your IE settings or internet connection?

Comment: Are you sure it's doing a post-back and it's not just IE8 being typical with not accepting the ENTER button as a submit? (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964734/hitting-enter-does-not-post-form-in-ie8 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631949/ie8-only-submits-with-button-not-submit ) -- could also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383190/ie8-form-not-submitting-intermittent

Comment: thanks for looking folks. That's the entire script - I copied it out into a separate file to make sure! It's not a network problem as I'm running this on my local machine with an apache install. I'm hitting the submit button, not using the enter key.

Comment: I realize this is a test script, and this doesn't solve your problem, but `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is unsafe in that context. Heads up.

Comment: thanks scoates - I wasn't aware of any issue with $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] - where's the risk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for wading in on this one.

It turns out the problem lay in an Apache module I had enabled.

It's a module to allow apache to use Windows authentication to identify a user via their Windows User id - mod_auth_sspi

The effect is caused by a known bug, in the module, but with a simple extra directive this can be worked around, until a fix is added in the next update, as described here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-auth-sspi/forums/forum/550583/topic/3392037

Answer (score 1):

That sounds very very bizarre. Does it happen in other versions of IE as well?

I can't tell you what the problem is, but here are my suggestions on how to diagnose it:

1. Print `$_REQUEST` rather than just `$_POST`, to see if the data is coming in via another method.
2. Use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to track exactly what is actually being sent by the browser.

Fiddler in particular has been very helpful for me a few times (mainly when debugging Ajax code), and will tell you exactly what was posted by the browser. If your web server is localhost, you can also use Fiddler to track what is received before PHP gets its hands on it. If not, you can use wireshark on the server if you have permissions for installing that sort of thing.

In addition to Fiddler, I would have suggested a browser-based tool like Firebug, but I don't know of one for IE that is good enough (The IE dev toolbar doesn't give you details of request and response data, as far as I know).

Comment: You can use Firebug Lite in IE, but I'm not sure what good it would do here.

Comment: thanks spudley - I'll try fiddler to see if that reveals anything. It's gonna be a few days now, as I'm home for the weekend - watch this space.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspicious that when the script is telling you that $_POST is empty, you did not actually POST the form. You can check by adding `print($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);` after your `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: I already did that, and request_method reports the method as "post" - thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Then it seems something nasty be going on. Reformat and reinstall Windows? Is that still the customary way?

Comment: Frankly, I'd reformat and install Linux, but our IT guys get nervous about anything non M$. Turns out we can't blame Mr Gates for this one though!

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting a file some of the time (i.e. with a file input) then make sure you set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the generated html? Is it possible that echo `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` isn't producing the output you're after, which messes up the form html, which messes up the POST?

Comment: thanks - I had checked, but it's worth noting for others if they're seeing problems with $_POST